# Nested Json response with Marshmellow - Flask

Tags: python, marshmallow

Iam trying to get a nested JSON response for OrderPlace, Product and Category objects using marshmallow to show API responses.

The data to display Users and Product for which the order placed is working but Product belongs to which category is not working.

Here's what I have tried

models.py

```
class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=True)
    total_product = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True, default=0)
    category_id = db.relationship('Category', backref="parentcategory", remote_side=[id])
    product = db.relationship('Product', backref='category')

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=True)
    order_detail = db.relationship('OrderPlaced', backref='product')
    
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    file = db.Column(db.String(20))
    filedata = db.LargeBinary()
    order_detail = db.relationship('OrderPlaced', backref="user")

    
class OrderPlaced(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)
    order_status = db.Column(db.String(10))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    modified_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

orders.py

```
class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class CategorySchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        

class ProductSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'category_id')
        model = Product
    category_id = ma.Nested(CategorySchema)

class OrderSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderPlaced
    
    user = ma.Nested(UserSchema)
    product = ma.Nested(ProductSchema)

api.add_resource(OrderDetailList, '/order/<int:user_id>')
class OrderDetailList(Resource):
    def get(self, user_id):
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()

        if not user:
            abort(404, message="User doesnt exist")
        
        user_orders = OrderPlaced.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id).all()
        if len(user_orders) == 0:
            abort(404, message="Currently no orders placed")
        else:
            return orders_schema.dump(user_orders)
```

The Response that I receive is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-08T15:31:50.103204",
        "order_status": "pending",
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "file": "file.pdf",
            "name": "john",
            "email": "blabla@gmail.com1"
        },
        "modified_at": "2023-02-08T15:31:50.103310",
        "quantity": 1,
        "product": {
            "category_id": {},
            "name": "Iphone 14"
        }
    }
]
```

Iam expecting:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-08T15:31:50.103204",
        "order_status": "pending",
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "file": "file.pdf",
            "name": "john",
            "email": "blabla@gmail.com1"
        },
        "modified_at": "2023-02-08T15:31:50.103310",
        "quantity": 1,
        "product": {
            "category_id": {    #This node is missing
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Apple"
             },
            "name": "Iphone 14"
        }
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in the `ProductSchema` you are referencing the column with the ForeignKey instead of the relationship. For this reason, the schema cannot be mapped. Use the backreference `category` created for the relationship `product` within the class `Category`.

```py
class ProductSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'category')
        model = Product
    category = ma.Nested(CategorySchema)
```

Comment: That worked, I was referencing the foreign id